# Angular 5 bypassSecurityTrustUrl is not working

Tags: angular5, angular-dom-sanitizer

I am trying to have a video with the url being from other site on my Angular 5 application. The video is not being played.

```
var myUrl = "example.com/myvideo.mp4";
var safeUrl = this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(myUrl);

this.videoUrl = safeUrl;
```

In the view I am trying to add the src to videoUrl.

Answer (score 1):

My bad, I had used value binding instead of property binding which solved the issue.